# "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1

Tags: nginx

NginxでSSLサーバを設定しようとしたところタイトルのエラーが出てしまいました。

以下にnginx.confとdefault.confを示します。

**nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server_tokens off;
}
```

**default.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  server_name ドメイン;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ドメイン/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ドメイン/privkey.pem;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE+RSAGCM:ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:!aNULL!eNull:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!DSS;

  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;';
  client_max_body_size 64M;

  # OCSP Staplingを有効にする
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ドメイン/fullchain.pem;

  # OCSP StaplingのためにはDNSリゾルバを指定する必要がある
  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  # Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
  location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:ポート;
  }

  location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  location ~ .*\.(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG|swf|SWF|css|CSS|js|JS|inc|INC|ico|ICO) {
    root ルート;
  }
}
```

SSLを使用しなかったときはこのようなエラーが出ていませんでした。なぜこのようなエラーがでてしまったのでしょうか。

Comment: Nginxを起動した時に普通に起動できたのでただのバグかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

default.conf は nginx.conf の http{} 内で include されていますが、
他の場所で include されていませんでしょうか。

Comment: おそらくされていないはずです。